# How to tackle the Codingbat String-2 oneTwo challenge?

Tags: java

Here is the problem statement:

> Given a string, compute a new string by moving the first char to come after the next two chars, so "abc" yields "bca". Repeat this process for each subsequent group of 3 chars, so "abcdef" yields "bcaefd". Ignore any group of fewer than 3 chars at the end.

Here is my code:

```
// oneTwo("abc") → "bca"
// oneTwo("tca") → "cat"
// oneTwo("tcagdo") → "catdog"  

public String oneTwo(String str) {
    String x = "";
    if (str.length() < 3) {
        return "";
        // return empty
    } else if (str.length() == 3) {
        String s = str.substring(1, str.length());
        x = s + str.substring(0, 1);      // last two + first char
    } else if (str.length() > 3) {
        int third = 2;
        // start with the third element index of 2
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            if (i == third) {
                // given three chars substring first char
                // substring last two chars and add that to x
                x += (str.substring(third - 1, third + 1) +
                        str.substring(third - 2, third - 2 + 1));
                third += 3;
                //work  with this line but why??????
            }
            //third +=3;
            // doesn't work with this line but why???????


        }// end of for loop
    }
    return x;
    // return modified string x
}
```

With `third +=3` inside of if statement work but when I put that outside of if statement I don't get the desired output. I don't really understand why?

Comment: Your problem has already been analysed. I suggest, you consume your input string instead of walking through the characters. This will give you the possibility to always only look at the first three characters. This way, all the index math you are doing (and will not be able to easily understand in three weeks from now  :-)), will be gone.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps:

```
public String oneTwo(String str) {
    String str2 = "";
    for(int i=0; i<str.length()-2; i+=3) {
        str2 = str2+str.substring(i+1,i+3)+str.charAt(i);
    }
    return str2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because putting it outside the loop will cause `third` to be increased far too often. After the first iteration `i is 0, third is 5`, next iteration yields `i=1, third=8; i=2, third=11; i=3, third=14`, etc. -> `i` will never reach third.

I would improve your code by dropping the entire if-statement, remove `third` all together and simply increment by 3 in the `for`-loop:

```
for( int i = 2; i < str.length(); i+=3){
    x += (str.substring(third-1, third+1) + 
          str.substring(third-2, third-2 + 1));
}
```

If I am not misinterpreting your code you are missing logic for leaving the last characters alone if they are not part of group of three characters.

Answer (score 0):

If you face such effects take a piece of paper and write down the values of the variables after each line of your code.

---

The `if` block creates an alternative execution path if the condition is true which is in every *third* loop iteration.

Anything behind  the `if` block is executed in *every* loop iteration.

So when the line in question is inside the `if` block (before the closing brace) the value in variable `third` is only changed every third loop iteration.

When you move the line behind the closing brace the assignment is outside the `if` block and therefore executed *every* loop iteration.

Answer (score 0):

For the comment = //work  with this line but why??????

The value of "third" variable gets changed in the for loop only with i is equal to third character, otherwise the value of third will keep on increasing eg.

when i = 0, third = 2
when i = 1, third = 5
when i = 2, third = 8

so the if statement never gets triggered and hence it doesn't work. Hope this makes sense.

PS - I highly recommend using IDE debugger to understand this properly.
PS - It's better to use charAt method as compared for substring method for performance reason

Answer (score 0):

```
public String oneTwo(String str) {
    String temp = "";
    String result = "";
    int i = 0;
    while (str.substring(i).length() >= 3) {
        temp = str.substring(i, i + 3);
        result += temp.substring(1) + temp.charAt(0);
        i += 3;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
public String oneTwo(String str) {

 String str1 = "";
 if(str.length()<3){
  return str1; 
 }else if(str.length()>=3){
    for(int i =0; i<str.length()-2; i=i+3){
            str1 = str1 + str.substring(i+1,i+3)+ str.substring(i,i+1);

        }
 }

 return str1;
}
```

Comment: Please add a description with your answer and explain how it is different from the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
public String oneTwo(String str) {
  if(str.length()<3)return "";
  return str.substring(1,3)+str.substring(0,1)+oneTwo(str.substring(3));
}
```

this is fairly simple as a recursive problem

Answer (score 0):

```
public String oneTwo(String str) {
        String newThreeChars = "";
        if(str.length()<3){
            return newThreeChars;
        }
        for(int i=0; i<str.length()/3; i+=3){
            String threeChars = str.substring(i,i+3);
            String redesigned = threeChars.substring(1) + threeChars.charAt(0);
            newThreeChars +=redesigned;
        }
        return newThreeChars;

    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Before answering an old question having other answers ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Also while this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/5698098), as that helps to improve the quality of your post. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and see [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Kindly edit your answer and add some explanations, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to look at...

```
public String oneTwo(String str) {
  int i = 0;
  String result = "";
  Character tmpChar = '\0';
  
  while(i <= str.length()-3){
    tmpChar = str.charAt(i);
    result = result + str.charAt(i+1) + str.charAt(i+2) + tmpChar;
    tmpChar = '\0';
    i = i + 3;
  }
  
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, We loop through each letter of the given String just stopping shy of the last two letters because the word we are looking for is three letters long. Then, we are returning true if there is two letter "b"'s exactly one character apart.

```
public boolean bobThere(String str) {
  for (int i = 0; i < str.length() - 2; i++) {
    if (str.charAt(i) == 'b' && str.charAt(i+2) == 'b')
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For string concatenation in a loop use StringBuilder:

```
public String oneTwo(String str) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length() - 2; i += 3) {
        sb.append(str.charAt(i + 1)).append(str.charAt(i + 2)).append(str.charAt(i));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```